# Magento 1.9 - User Roles Permission return Fatal error

Tags: fatal-error, permissions, user-roles, magento1.9.2.3

If i click System -> Permission -> Roles if i click any of roles return following error,

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Cmsmquickview_Helper_Data' not found in /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547**

How to solve thi Issue?

Comment: First, you need to check whether you have defined your custom helper in **app/code/[Package]/[Module]/etc/config.xml**

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I have too many custom modules, may i know what is the correct way to declare helper in app/code/[Package]/[Module]/etc/config.xml Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumptions for answer:**

- Your module's package name is **Stack** and your module name is **Cmsmquickview**.
- Your module resides in the **local** codepool.

Now the definition of your helper class (in **`app/code/local/Stack/Cmsmquickview/etc/config.xml`** file) should look like:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <cmsmquickview>
            <class>Stack_Cmsmquickview_Helper</class>
        </cmsmquickview>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

and the helper class file (**`app/code/local/Stack/Cmsmquickview/Helper/Data.php`**) should be like:

```
<?php
class Stack_Cmsmquickview_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
  // your code here
}
```

now you should call the helper like this:

```
Mage::helper('cmsmquickview');
```

**Update (after looking into the attached module by @zus):**

Change

```
<children>
    <quickview translate="title" module="cmsmquickview">
        <title>Quick View Settings</title>
        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
    </quickview>
</children>
```

to:

```
<children>
    <quickview translate="title" module="ajaxcart">
        <title>Quick View Settings</title>
        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
    </quickview>
</children>
```

in **`app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/etc/adminhtml.xml`** file. Notice  **module="ajaxcart"**.

This is because you have defined helper as **ajaxcart** in **config.xml** file.

Comment: Here is my module : https://github.com/ZusZus/Cmsmquickview  and file ->  app\code\local\Cmsmart\AjaxCart\etc\adminhtml.xml   line -> 21, error : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Cmsmquickview_Helper_Data' not found in /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547   @Mohit Kumar Arora

Comment: @zus, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Working, thank you.

Comment: Small doubt how to solve following error -> https://snipboard.io/I2FrSH.jpg @Mohit Kumar Arora